# Como usar o Cascade Delete entre duas tabelas?

Tags: php, sql

Tenho 2 tabelas:

**produtos**

*id*

*nome*

...

**produtos_fotos**

*id*

*id_produto*

*foto*

No PHP irei fazer um DELETE no Produto, e por consequência quero que automaticamente delete TODAS as fotos do produto deletado, claro que apague também o registro na tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso, primeiro devo mexer com Cascade (SQL), depois no PHP para deletar os arquivos, certo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você coloca na sua FK on DELETE CASCADE quando você deletar a tabela o efeito será cascata, ou seja se deletar o Produto suas fotos serão deletadas automaticamente e você não precisa deletar no PHP pois isso é automático no banco. Porém o cascade deverá ser utilizado com cautela, se você ainda precisar de alguma informação da tabela utilize SET NULL e ao MAPEAR O FK deixe com NULL.