# Delete em Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

Tenho três tabelas: Alunos, Cursos e Professores. Estou tentando executar um delete na tabela Cursos, mas ela ela tem relação com outras tabelas. Como faço para executar a exclusão?

```
create database flexPeak;
use flexPeak;
create table ALUNO(
ID_ALUNO int primary key not null auto_increment,
Nome_Aluno varchar(20) not null,
DATA_NASCIMENTO_ALUNO varchar(20) not null,
CEP_ALUNO int not null,
LOGRADOURO_ALUNO varchar (20) not null,
NUMERO_ALUNO int not null,
BAIRRO_ALUNO varchar(20) not null,  
CIDADE_ALUNO varchar(20) not null,
ESTADO_ALUNO varchar(20) not null,
DATA_CRIACAO_ALUNO varchar(20) not null,
Aluno_CURSO_ID int not null,
foreign key(Aluno_CURSO_ID) 
references CURSO(ID_CURSO)
);

create table CURSO(
ID_CURSO int primary key not null auto_increment,
NOME_CURSO varchar(20) not null,
DATA_CRIACAO_CURSO date not null,
ID_PROFESSOR_CURSO int not null ,
foreign key(ID_PROFESSOR_CURSO) 
references PROFESSOR(ID_PROFESSOR)
);

create table PROFESSOR(  
ID_PROFESSOR int not null primary key auto_increment,
NOME_PROFESSOR  varchar(20) not null,
DATA_NASCIMENTO_PROFESSOR date not null,
DATA_CRIACAO_PROFESSOR date not null
);
```

Comment: Se não precisa manter registros como historico, deve colocar um `delete cascate`. [Como usar o Cascade Delete entre duas tabelas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179977/91)

Comment: Muito obrigadoo!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE SUATABELA DROP CONSTRAINT FK_SUACHAVE
```

E tente excluir sua tabela. Espero ter ajudado. =)